# В каком пакете находится request?

Tags: java

В исходном коде одной программы написан такой код.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder ( )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот класс с равной вероятностью может быть частью какого-либо большого фреймворка, сторонней библиотеки или клиентским классом самой программы. По одному только имени класса нельзя с уверенностью сказать, к какому именно пакету он относится, так как одинаковые имена классов могут встречаться в разных частях и это имя зависит только от фантазии разработчика, занимающегося конкретным приложением\библиотекой\фреймворком. Тем более, такое "популярное" название, как реквест .. Например, такой класс есть в библиотеке *okhttp*.

Для того, чтобы узнать наверняка, вам нужно посмотреть импорт этого класса в начале вашей программы.

Например, сэмпл-класс, [использующий библиотеку okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/simple-client/src/main/java/okhttp3/sample/OkHttpContributors.java) и класс [`Request`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.html) из этой библиотеки. В начале сэмпла [видим импорт](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/4c1e981661468712eb59f6c9b25da94f7849dabe/samples/simple-client/src/main/java/okhttp3/sample/OkHttpContributors.java#L10):

```
import okhttp3.Request;
```

отсюда предельно ясно, что данный класс `Request` принадлежит библиотеке *okhttp3*

Comment: Да, это именно эта библиотека. А откуда можно узнавать о разных либах, которые есть для java, в google?

Comment: @xverizex есть разные агрегаторы. например [N#1 на русском](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links/blob/master/link-rus/readme.md) и более полный [N#2 на английском](https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java/blob/master/README.md). эти два покрывают 99% того, что реально используется. точнее, первый - русский вариант второго

Comment: о, спасибо.....